# How to check for CML child nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xmlreader

I'm using `xmlreader` to read an XML-file. I want to identify whether an element has child nodes or not.

Currently, I use the `IsEmptyElement` method to find whether there are child elements. I found out that, even if the tag contains text data and not an element, it returns as true.

```
if (!file.IsEmptyElement) {
    elem.subElems.Add(readXml(file));
}
```

How van I fix this issue using the xml reader? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have to check, use [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) instead... I found it to be easier to understand and code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("YourDocument");

XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

if (root.HasChildNodes)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Reader:

```
using (XmlReader reader = ...)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == ...))
        {
            Int32 childrenCount = CountChildred(reader, XmlNodeType.Element);
            // Your code...

public static Int32 CountChildred(XmlReader node, XmlNodeType type)
{
    Int32 count = 0;
    Int32 currentDepth = node.Depth;
    Int32 validDepth = currentDepth + 1;

    while (node.Read() && (node.Depth != currentDepth))
    {
        if ((node.NodeType == type) && (node.Depth == validDepth))
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Behavior of [IsEmptyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.isemptyelement.aspx) is expected, and really with reader it is the only information you can get when reader is positioned at the beginning of the element. Reader at that point have not tried to read the inner XML of the element so there is no information if there are any child nodes, text nodes or mix of both.

To fix you need to read each child element and individually add them to you list (or whatever you have).